# Is there any option to set cors (Cross Origin Resouce Sharing) through s3cmd tool?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, cloud, s3cmd

Is there any command in s3cmd http://s3tools.org/ through which i can set cors (Cross Origin Resouce Sharing)

I have checked these sites.

http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--manage-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Is there any command through which i can set cors rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For your tool of choice, it looks like [the S3cmd usage documentation](http://s3tools.org/usage) has this command:

> s3cmd setcors FILE s3://BUCKET

Otherwise:

[AWS put-bucket-cors Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-cors.html)
may be what you are looking for?

Use

> aws s3api put-bucket-cors --generate-cli-skeleton >cors.json

to create a json input file, and after editing it, you can use:

> aws s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket [bucket name] --cors-configuration file://cors.json

to overwrite the existing cors configuration of the bucket.

I use only the "CORSRules" stanza in the root {} of my cors.json, because everything else is handled by the cli.